# React Native - Repeat SVG Background using react-native-svg-transformer

Tags: react-native

I would like to know how to create a repeating background (like background-repeat: repeat-y; property in css) from a SVG file that I downloaded from https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/

I'm using react-native-svg and react-native-svg-transformer in order to display SVG.

Here is my code.

```
import Background from "../assets/images/background.svg";


return (
<Background />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any support from `react-native-svg` and `react-native-svg-transformer` packages for your requirement.

Instead of using SVG image you can achieve this by using a `png` or `jpeg` image.
like this

```
      <Image
        style={{ flex: 1, width: undefined, height: undefined }}
        source={require('./test.png')}
        resizeMode="repeat"
      />
```

if you need to display a particular svg image, then you can download the svg image from here https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/, and then you can convert that svg image in png or jpeg online like https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/
and then use the png image in react-native.

example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

u can use `<Pattern>` element from `react-native-svg`, https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#pattern. 
first flatlist element have svg repeated background.

[image]